# Blank Box If No Data Inputted

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

This might sound hugely amateurish but I have a spreadsheet for my Pilot Log Book as I am a student. I have boxes stating my Take Off time and Landing time. In this case:

13:40 **(H5)** to 14:40 **(I5)**

This means I would put down 1:00 (**K5**) for the amount flown.

What formula would I input to say **"I5 - H5 ="**, but if there is no value in I5 or H5, leave K5 blank?

Comment: Works wonders Thank you! Upvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(H5<>"", I5<>""), I5-H5, )
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((H5:H<>"") * (I5:I<>""), TEXT(I5:I-H5:H, "hh:mm"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Amazing ! I know this was a minor question to answer but I appreciate it, I will try it in my sheet and let you know .